# Value does not get updated Angular 7 TS

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, insert-update

UPDATE:
My code does not seem to be updating the selected value with the new value (the value that is written in the input field "newVb"). It sais that 'this.newVarde' is undefined when it comes to the line 'this.selectedVarde = this.newVarde'. And in the end it adds a new value rather than update the selected one.  But why, I don't get...

.ts

```
export class RightMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  public selectedVarde: this.selectedVarde;
  public newVarde: Varde;



  constructor(private _vardeService: VardeService) {
  }

updateVarde() {


    var beskrivning = this.selectedVarde;
    var newVarde = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('newVb')).value;


   this.varde = {

     Beskrivning: newVarde,
   }


    this.selectedVarde = this.newVarde;
    this._vardeService.updateVarde(this.varde).subscribe(() => { console.log("Lyckat") });


  }
```

And then my .html:

```
<label for="updateVarde">T:Värdet som du vill uppdatera</label>
            <select [(ngModel)]="selectedVarde" id="selectedVarde" name="updateVarde" class="form-control" required >
              <option *ngFor="let varde of allaVarden" [ngValue]="varde">{{varde.beskrivning}}</option> 
            </select>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateVarde()" style="margin-left:4%;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vardeModal" data-dismiss="modal">T:Redigera valt värde</button>
            <label for="beskrivning">T:Nytt värde: </label>
            <input class="input" style="width:10%;" id="newVb" type="text">
```

Greatful for any tips on what is wrong with the code

Comment: What this.beskrivning variable contains when page is first loaded ?

Comment: The selected value from a drop-down which I then want to modify so that the newVarde replaces it (beskrivning will get updated with the input from newVb)

Comment: scope variables and local variables are confused here      var beskrivning = this.selectedVarde that why you are getting undefined.

Comment: I only define them as local. What do you mean? See updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its correct, its undefined because you didn't set the value for it.

These are your component defined properties/variables

```
public selectedVarde: Varde;
public newVarde: Varde;
public beskrivning: Varde;
```

You then defined and initialized new scoped variables with the same name here in the method.

```
var beskrivning = this.selectedVarde;
var newVarde = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('newVb')).value;

this.varde = {
 Beskrivning: newVarde,
}
```

Hence you reach the following line `this.newVarde` is still undefined

```
this.beskrivning = this.newVarde;
```

**Edit:**

Instead of creating a new variable you can use the ones you have already defined.

```
this.beskrivning = this.selectedVarde;
this.newVarde = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('newVb')).value;

this.varde = {
 Beskrivning: this.newVarde,
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Since so `newVarde` in your method `updateVarde` does not refer to the `newVarde` in your component then you have to declare and initialize it in the method.

```
this.beskrivning = this.selectedVarde;
const newVarde = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('newVb')).value;

this.varde = {
 Beskrivning: newVarde,
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand but if I remove them from properties then I will get errors in my method because they are needed as properties.

Comment: Then dont define new variable using var.....use the variable that you have define in your component.....remove `var` and replace it with `this`

Comment: Thank u, that actually helped me retrive this.beskrivning (now called selectedVarde) so it is no longer undefined. But newVarde is still undefined. I understand that I should be able to solve it the same way as I did with selectedVarde but how do you declare a propertie based on an input from the html?

Comment: If I do as you did and write as you did in your edit I get the following error:'(TS) Type string is not assignable to type Varde'

Comment: have you define `varde` in your component?

Comment: Yes, "public varde: Varde;"

Comment: `(TS) Type string is not assignable to type Varde` is because you declared `newVarde` as `Varde`. Do you use it in another place? if not you do not need to declare it on the component level.

Comment: It is no longer undefined but somehow the method ends up adding a value instead om updating the selected one.. Thanks for the help with the undefined-issue tho :)